# Save variable content to text file

Tags: matlab

I have 96 x 96 images, I want to convert each image to pixels and save it to a text file. This is an example of code :

```
frame = imread('c.jpg');
allpixels = reshape(frame, 96*96, 3)
```

The Output of  the command window is :

```
a

allpixels =

   211   194   176
   200   183   163
   186   169   143
   170   150   123
   154   133   104
   149   128    99
   156   135   106
   157   136   109
   155   135   110
   148   126   102
   147   123    97
   143   118    88 
   .....
```

I want to save only the content of the variable **allpixels** to a text file. It means the text file should be exactly like this :

```
211   194   176
200   183   163
186   169   143
170   150   123
154   133   104
149   128    99
156   135   106
157   136   109
155   135   110
148   126   102
147   123    97
143   118    88
```

I have used :

```
diary('out.txt');
diary on
```

But **out.txt** will contain all the command window output, like this :

```
a
allpixels =

  9216×3 <a href="matlab:helpPopup uint8" style="font-weight:bold">uint8</a> matrix

   211   194   176
   200   183   163
   186   169   143
   170   150   123
   154   133   104
   149   128    99
   156   135   106
   157   136   109
   155   135   110
   148   126   102
   147   123    97
   143   118    88
```

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`diary` is for activity log of your MATLAB session. To store the specific matrix you can use the following code:

```
dlmwrite('out.txt', a, 'delimiter', ' ');
```

See the details [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmwrite.html).